# What is the best practice for fetching multiple data with router in react?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-context

I'm new at web dev and I am still trying to figure out the best practices.
I was actually using useEffects on components themselves to fetch data on my server, which is working fine but I figured out that my data is being fetched everytime I change route (since I believe the component is being rerendered), which are unnecessary requests to the server as the data will probably not change, and multiple fetch calls can be done for one component.

So I considered to use the useContext hook for each one of my API calls, but I'm afraid this is a bad practice, so I would love to have advices on that.

The code would actually look like this :

```
const ServiceContext = React.createContext<any>(null);

export const useServices = () => {
  return React.useContext(ServiceContext);
};

export const ServiceProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [services, setServices] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchServices = async () => {
      try {
        const services = await dataProvider.getList("services");
        setServices(services.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setServices(null);
      }
    };
    fetchServices();
  }, []);
  return (
    <ServiceContext.Provider value={services}>
      {children}
    </ServiceContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And how I would provide the contexts :

```
export const ClientContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  return (
          <ServiceProvider>
           <Provider2>
            <Providerx....>
             {children}
            </Providerx....>
           </Provider2>        
          </ServiceProvider>
   );
};
```

I would have actually only 3 contexts for now, one for each data I have to fetch, but I'm scared it becomes too heavy for the start of the application if I have more of them, I'm looking for a solution usable for big projects too.

I tried to look for solutions on documentation / forums but I couldn't find an answer.

**Edit :**

I've found a workaround that solves the issue, even though I am not sure if it is ok to do that. I create a separate file :

```
let data = null;

export const GetData = async () => {
  if (data === null) {
    data = await fetch();
  }
  return data;
};
```

And in component :

```
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const fetchedData = await GetData();
      setData(data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

**Edit2 :**

For people who are interested, react-query is a good library that handles these issues. https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/overview

Comment: What is the issue the code you are using? I don't see any issue here fetching the data when the app mounts.

Comment: I am not sure that is why I am asking. As I said, I am scared that it becomes too heavy if I have to much data to fetch, and having so many contexts feels wrong, I feel like there might be a better solution, like fetching data only when needed and only once.

Comment: Your question is actually quite subjective then, on the verge of being off-topic. Superlatively quantified (*best this, fastest that, etc*) tend towards opinionated answers. The short, easy answer is that you should fetch data only when you need it. You might need *some* data when the app mounts, you might only need *some other* data when accessing specific pages/routes/areas of the app.

Comment: for the useeffect you can try adding a dependancy so data is only fetched after that dependancy changes,or leave it blank so data is only fetched when the components mounts.Alternatively you can use reactQuery library here is link to their official docs https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview

Comment: You might also consider persisting state to localStorage and re-initializing state when the app mounts, and then do a check if you've already got the data and only fetch/refetch if it's missing or considered "stale". Are you using any Redux for global state management, or just starting out with a React context? What you do and need depends on what you are using and what your app needs.

Comment: I would like to fetch the data only when needed, so use fetching on the component. The problem with that is that it was fetched every time I come back to that route, which is what I wanted to avoid with the contexts (which has an other problem which is fetching the data even though it is not necessarily needed).
So I was wondering if I could fetch data only when needed + only once using routes. (Sorry for my english)
Edit: Your last answer makes more sense, Im only using contexts for now, should I consider Redux for this issue ? Or are local storage sufficient ?

Comment: Louis: I know about array dependencies, problem is components are rerendered every time I leave and come back to a route, which calls an other fetch

Comment: In the interim you might consider something *between* fetching in a Context provider at the root of the app and some page at a leaf node, something like fetching data in a common parent/ancestor component that remains mounted while the app is rendering different content/pages. If your app is still relatively small though there might not be much between the two extremes, but hopefully the idea/concept makes sense.

Comment: I have a bit of difficulties to understand the concept since I am still working on small apps, but I'll sleep on it ! I'm keeping the contexts for now then, thank you for your help :)

Comment: The basic design pattern is React's [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) pattern. Using a React Context is just a specific implementation of this pattern that fixes the issue of "props drilling" when the component's aren't a direct parent/child pair.

Comment: I've edited my question, I found a workaround that solves the issue ! Thanks again for your help.